# How to search for multiple matches using the IN operator in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

[image]
Right now I am filtering my rows by using the WHERE operator and 2 conditional statements. It seems somewhat inefficient that I am writing 2 conditions. Would it be possible to check if "`amznbida`" and "`ksga`" are in the array by only writing in one statement?

## standardSQL

```
  -- Get all the keys

SELECT 
  *

FROM `encoded-victory-198215.DFP_TEST.test3`

WHERE 

  "amznbida" IN UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT name FROM UNNEST(keywords)))

AND 

  "ksga"IN UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT name FROM UNNEST(keywords)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the UNNEST(ARRAY( part and leave the subquery - you should be fine.
working example:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  t in (select * from unnest(a)) condition
FROM unnest([
    struct('a' as t, ['a', 'b', 'c'] as a),
    ('b',['r', 'f'])
  ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `encoded-victory-198215.DFP_TEST.test3`
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM UNNEST(keywords) WHERE name IN ("amznbida", "ksga"))
```

Yu can test, play with above using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `encoded-victory-198215.DFP_TEST.test3` AS (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY<STRUCT<value ARRAY<STRING>, name STRING>>[
      STRUCT(['ksg-1', 'ksg-2'], 'ksga'), STRUCT(['amznbid-1', 'amznbid-2'], 'amznbida')
    ] keywords,
    1 impression UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    ARRAY<STRUCT<value ARRAY<STRING>, name STRING>>[
      STRUCT(['xxx-1', 'xxx-2'], 'xxxa'), STRUCT(['amznbid-1', 'amznbid-2'], 'amznbida')
    ] keywords,
    2 impression 
)
SELECT *
FROM `encoded-victory-198215.DFP_TEST.test3`
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM UNNEST(keywords) WHERE name IN ("amznbida", "ksga"))
```

with result

```
Row keywords.value  keywords.name   impression   
1   ksg-1           ksga            1    
    ksg-2            
    amznbid-1       amznbida         
    amznbid-2
```